# How to periodically set state?

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate

I am trying to build a countdown app for special days for example 11 d 2 h 30 m 23s to the new year but I can't reload my state every second so it just shows me the second that I loaded the page I don't know how to dynamically reload the page.

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    class RopSayac extends StatefulWidget {
      _RopSayacState createState() => _RopSayacState();
    }

    class _RopSayacState extends State<RopSayac> {

      var now = DateTime.now().second.toString();
      String asd(){
        setState(() {
        now = DateTime.now().second.toString();

        });
        return now;
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {


        return Container(
          child: new Text(asd()),
        );
      }
    }
```

This is what I got and it doesn't reload time. I am pretty new on the flutter.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49952901/flutter-timer-issue-during-testing

Comment: see `Timer` or `Metronome` classes

Comment: You can use setInterval property

Answer (score 40, accepted):

As pskink and Günter mentioned, use a `Timer`. You can even use the `periodic` constructor that would fit well your scenario.

Note you don't need the `asd()` function. When you call `setState()`, the `build` method will be called automatically passing the new `now` property value.

If you want, use `initState` to set an initial value and, as in this example, setup the `Timer`.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(title: 'Timer Periodic Demo', home: RopSayac());
  }
}

class RopSayac extends StatefulWidget {
  _RopSayacState createState() => _RopSayacState();
}

class _RopSayacState extends State<RopSayac> {
  String _now;
  Timer _everySecond;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // sets first value
    _now = DateTime.now().second.toString();

    // defines a timer 
    _everySecond = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (Timer t) {
      setState(() {
        _now = DateTime.now().second.toString();
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: new Text(_now),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Now ı understand init state logic better. Flutter feels like weird after java and .net

Comment: Can you also explain what does dipose() do

Comment: `dispose` is called when the widget is no longer needed and it's about to be destroyed. Let's say you open a connection in `initState` and for some reason you keep it open, you would implement the `dispose` method as it would be a good time to close that connection. That's kind of a bad example, but gives you the idea. [Check also this](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/State/dispose.html).

Answer (score 6):

This recursive method should be enough for what you want. The `seconds` set as 1 will keep triggering `setState` each second, thus refreshing your widget tree.

```
void _timer() {
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1)).then((_) {
      setState(() {
        print("1 second closer to NYE!");
        // Anything else you want
      });
      _timer();
    });
  }
```

Comment: Isnt there a need to call the timer function at least once in the program?

Comment: Yes. You should call it at least once.

Comment: This will crash when you widget does off screen. Check the logs.

Answer (score 5):

There's this excellent library called [timer_builder](https://pub.dev/packages/timer_builder). I think it'll help you out.

Example from the pub page:

```
import 'package:timer_builder/timer_builder.dart';

class ClockWidget extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TimerBuilder.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), //updates every second
      builder: (context) {
        return Text("${DateTime.now()}");
      }
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: Useful when the entire application is time-based

Answer (score -2):

Here's what I do.  In my case I'm polling a webservice in _liveUpdate()

```
void startUpdates(AppState appState) async {
await new Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 100));
while (true) {
  _liveUpdate();
  appState.setState(() {});

  await new Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds : 15));
}
```

Comment: This is RealBadAdvice(tm)