# Flutter - how to update screen with latest api response

Tags: flutter, api, dart, flutter-state

I want to update the screen whenever I call the API. Right now I have the following

```
Future<String> getData() async {
var response = await http.get(
    Uri.parse('https://www.api_endpoint.com'),
    headers: {
      'Accept':'application/json'
    }
);

Timer.periodic(Duration(microseconds: 1000), (_) {
  this.setState(() {
    data = json.decode(response.body);
    print(data); //I can see this in the console/logcat
  });
});

}

@override
void initState() {
  this.getData();
}
```

from the line above `print(data);` I can see the latest api responses in console/logcat but the screen doesn't update with the new values. I can't get my head around why the latest responses aren't shown on screen when `this.setState()` is called every second with the Timer... all feedback is welcome. Thanks

Comment: It's impossible to say without knowing what your build method looks like.

Answer (score 1):

`Future` executes once and returns just `one` result. `initState()` executed when creating a widget, this is also usually once. For your tasks it is better to use `Streams`, my solution is not the best in terms of architecture, but as an example it works.

```
  //We create a stream that will constantly read api data
  Stream<String> remoteApi = (() async* {
    
    const url = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1";
    
    //Infinite loop is not good, but I have a simple example
    while (true) {
      try {

        var response = await Dio().get(url);
        
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          
             //remote api data does not change, so i will add a timestamp
              yield response.data.toString() +
              DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();
        }

        //Pause of 1 second after each request
        await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));

      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
      }
    }
  })();

  //On the screen we are waiting for data and display it on the screen
 // A new piece of data will refresh the screen

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder<String>(
        stream: remoteApi,
        builder: (
          BuildContext context,
          AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot,
        ) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active ||
              snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return const Text('Error');
            } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return Center(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                  child: Text(
                    snapshot.data.toString(),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                ),
              );
            } else {
              return const Center(child: Text('Empty data'));
            }
          } else {
            return Center(child: Text('State: ${snapshot.connectionState}'));
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Or simplest solution

```
 Future<String> remoteApi() async {
    try {
      const url = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1";
      var response = await Dio().get(url);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        return response.data.toString() +
            DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();
      } else {
        throw ("Error happens");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      throw ("Error happens");
    }
  }
  
 var displayValue = "Empty data";
  
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Center(child: Text(displayValue)),
              Center(
                child: ElevatedButton.icon(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    displayValue = await remoteApi();
                    setState(() {});
                  },
                  label: const Text('Get API'),
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.download),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply @Александр Инженер, I like the simpliest solution but having issue trying to integrate timer into it. Can you assist...

Answer (score -1):

Ah, you don't actually *call* your API every timer tick, you just decode *the same body from the first call*.

If you want to call your API periodically, you need to move the actual http.get call inside the timer method.

Comment: thanks for reply @nvoigt but just to clarify, I **do** see new values in the response so isn't that a new call each time or were you referencing something else?

Comment: If you see *different* values each timer tick, then that is the result from code you have not posted here. what you posted cannot have different results each time.

Answer (score -2):

Got it using the answer [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53767950/how-to-periodically-set-state)... moved the Timer that called `this.setState()` to the initState method

```
@override
void initState() {
 this.getData();
 _everySecond = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 5), (Timer t) {
   setState(() {
    getData();
   });
 });
}
```

Once I searched for how to update the state, change state, etc. found the solution quickly...