# SetState in ternary operator

Tags: flutter, setstate, conditional-operator

I want to change the color of the text displaying the scheduled time, if the scheduled time is past the current time then it should change to red and if its in the future then it wont change. This works properly but it only changes state when I click on another button. I am using a ternary operator like this:

```
color: (run(todoController.todos[index].date,
            todoController.todos[index].time)
            .compareTo(tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local))>0)
            ? Theme.of(context).hintColor
            : Colors.redAccent,
```

How do you add setState in a ternary operator? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the neater solution would be moving the logic of the comparison of time in a separate function which will be called each 2/5 second depending on your app. In that function, you can change the state and make sure to use color depending on the state.

The code for checking the future time each minute

```
var cron = new Cron();
cron.schedule(new Schedule.parse('*/3 * * * *'), () async {
  if(run(todoController.todos[index].date,
        todoController.todos[index].time)
        .compareTo(tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local))>0){
    setState(() {
      isFutureTime = true;
    });
  }
});
```

I have used corn. [CORN documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/cron)
Your Widget color code would look like this.

```
isFutureTime == false? Theme.of(context).hintColor : Colors.redAccent,
```

**isFutureTime** is the state boolean variable. You can follow this [StackOverflow answer on changing the state periodically.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53787944/13160239)

Comment: Can you also add the isFutureTime function?

Comment: @RohithNambiar I have added the function code using CORN. Let me know if it works.

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work and also there were no errors shown in the debug console, I am using Getx, so any way to set state in getx?