# Timer is never cancelled when GetxController is deleted in flutter

Tags: flutter, timer, flutter-getx

Let's say I have two screens (Screen A & Screen B). I navigate from Screen A to B using the following method:

```
Get.toNamed('/screen_b');
```

I have a timer in screen b that calls a function or prints a statement. The timer code is inside GetxController.

```
class Controller extends GetxController{

 
  Timer? timer;

@override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
      timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 5), (Timer t) {
        print('timer is running');
        //DO SOMETHING
      });

    }

  }

@override
  void dispose() {
    print('I am disposed');
    timer!.cancel();
    super.dispose();

  }

  @override
  void onClose() {
    timer!.cancel();
    super.onClose();
    print('I am closed');


  }

}
```

I've tried to cancel timer using onDispose & onClose methods provided by GetxController but it looks like timer is never cancelled. When I navigate back to Screen A, the print statement `**timer is running**` keeps on running forever and the statement is printed 6/7 times. What did I do wrong? When I go back from Screen B to Screen A, Getx prints the following statement

```
[GETX] CLOSE TO ROUTE /screen_b
[GETX] "Controller" onDelete() called
[GETX] "Controller" deleted from memory
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter: Timer Issue During Testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49952901/flutter-timer-issue-during-testing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the `onInit()` function try to use this:

Replace the `Timer t` -> `timer`

```
void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
      timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 5), (timer) {
        print('timer is running');
      });
    }
  }
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer. Still the timer is not being cancelled when i go back to Screen A.

Comment: For confirmation does the two screens have different GetxControllers?

Comment: Yes. Screen A controller and Screen B controller

Comment: I tried using your code and and it was fine...

Comment: are you using bindings? Also, could you share your Screen B View class?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did a noob mistake. I was accidentally creating the timer object inside a for loop. Thank you for your time as you assured me it worked for you, i rechecked my whole code and found the culprit. I will mark your code as answer.

Answer (score 0):

I do have same problem as you last time when you already deleted the controller but the time still run ticking as i did is if the timer is mounted.

```
ifTimerMounted(){
 final itimer = timer == null ? false : timer!.isActive;
 if(itimer){
   timer!.cancel();
 }else{
  // Or Do Nothing Leave it Blank
  log('Timer Stop Running')
  }
}
```

try to put this in onClose

```
@override
  void onClose() {
    super.onClose();
   ifTimerMounted();  
  }
```

Comment: Just used your method in Screen B controller, it does not work :(